# I have a static website built using HTML, CSS and Javascript. How do I integrate this with a SQLite3 database accessed with the Python API?

Tags: python, sqlite, static-site

Title question says it all. I was trying to figure out how I could go about integrating the database created by sqlite3 and communicate with it through Python from my website.

If any further information is required about the development environment, please let me know.

Comment: If this is too broad, please direct me to resources that could help me carry this out.

Comment: You can't. I know you don't want to hear that but you just can't unless you do some silly tricks like running a python script 24/7 that interacts with the database and alters the html files.

Comment: Then how is it supposed to be used? What is the point of the db even having a Python API?

Comment: sqlite3 databases aren't used for websites only. In fact, they are rarely used for websites. You can create a website using sqlite3 and python, but you'd have to use something like django or CherryPy or create your own lightweight http server... or apache and a modwsgi script... anyway that's probably not what your looking for...

Comment: I think this could be turned into a decent question, but you need to edit the question and tell us exactly what you want to do with the information from the database, and what web server you're using. Plenty of sites are mostly static and use just a little bit of programming for a few parts of the site, it sounds like you're looking for something like that but we need a little more information to get you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are using JQuery at all but you should use AJAX to make calls to the python api.

Jquery Method:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST", //OR GET
 url: yourapiurl,
 data: datatosend,
 success: success, //Callback when request is successful that contains the SQlite data
 dataType: dataType
});
```

Javascript Method:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST",yourapiurl,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

The responseText attribute of the XMLHttpRequest be populated with the SQlite  data from the api

Answer (score 2):

Use XMLHttpRequest (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to call your python script and put the results back in your webpage.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your needs has changed and you are going into direction where static web site is not sufficient any more.
Firstly, I would pick appropriate Python framework for your needs. if static website was sufficient until recently Django can be perfect for you.
Next I would suggest describing your DB schema for ORM used in chosen framework. I see no point in querying your DB using SQL until you would have a specific reason.
And finally, I would start using static content of your website as templates, replacing places where dynamic data is required. Django internal template language can be easily used that way. If not, Jinja2 also could be good.
My advise is base on many assumptions, as your question is quite open and undefined.
Anyway, I think it would be the best way to start transition period from static to dynamic.